# XGBoost: While using the `eval_set` in .fit causing Error

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to train the model using Xgboost. The code is doing split using `KFold`. And for each fold, it's running the Xgboost model using `fit`. Within the `fit` function, I'm trying to evaluate both train and valid data to check if the errors. And then doing the prediction in `test` set.

I'm running the following code using Xgboost.

```
kf = GroupKFold(n_splits=4)

for trn_idx, test_idx in kf.split(X, groups=X.year) :
    x_train, x_valid = X.iloc[trn_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
    y_train, y_valid = y.iloc[trn_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
    
    
    xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor( 
                        booster = 'dart',
                        eta = 0.1,
                        gamma = 0,
                        colsample_bytree = 0.7,
                       n_estimators  = 1200,
                       max_depth     = 1,
                           reg_alpha = 1.1,
                           reg_lambda = 1.1,
                           subsample = 0.03,
                       eval_metric=my_smape)
    
    xgb_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(x_train, y_train), (x_valid,y_valid)], early_stopping_rounds=20,
                    verbose=True)
```

But I'm getting the following error. I checked [this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) doc, and my code is according to the doc. Can someone please help me find the solution?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-81b11a21472c> in <module>
     23                        eval_metric=my_smape)
     24 
---> 25     xgb_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
     26         eval_set=[(x_valid,y_valid)], early_stopping_rounds=20,
     27                         verbose=True)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    573         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    574             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 575         return f(**kwargs)
    576 
    577     return inner_f

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    959             xgb_model, eval_metric, params, early_stopping_rounds, callbacks
    960         )
--> 961         self._Booster = train(
    962             params,
    963             train_dmatrix,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    573         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    574             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 575         return f(**kwargs)
    576 
    577     return inner_f

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks, custom_metric)
    180             break
    181         bst.update(dtrain, i, obj)
--> 182         if cb_container.after_iteration(bst, i, dtrain, evals):
    183             break
    184 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\callback.py in after_iteration(self, model, epoch, dtrain, evals)
    237             for _, name in evals:
    238                 assert name.find('-') == -1, 'Dataset name should not contain `-`'
--> 239             score: str = model.eval_set(evals, epoch, self.metric, self._output_margin)
    240             splited = score.split()[1:]  # into datasets
    241             # split up `test-error:0.1234`

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in eval_set(self, evals, iteration, feval, output_margin)
   1860         if feval is not None:
   1861             for dmat, evname in evals:
-> 1862                 feval_ret = feval(
   1863                     self.predict(dmat, training=False, output_margin=output_margin), dmat
   1864                 )

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in inner(y_score, dmatrix)
     99     def inner(y_score: np.ndarray, dmatrix: DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    100         y_true = dmatrix.get_label()
--> 101         return func.__name__, func(y_true, y_score)
    102     return inner
    103 

AttributeError: '_PredictScorer' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've run `make_scorer()` on your custom metric. Try supplying the original function as `eval_metric` instead, this should fix the issue.